# What variables are allowed in Header/Footer fields in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, what variables like $FILE$ or $PAGE$ are allowed in the Header/Footer fields when printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what variables are available is not documented in the help guide at all. But a few minutes of digging in the open source portion of IntelliJ IDEA code shows that the [TextPainter](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/ff16ce78a1e0ddb6e67fd1dbc6e6a597e20d483a/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/codeEditor/printing/TextPainter.java) class does the token replacement. And upon looking at it, it's apparent that the `$FILE$` and `$PAGE$` tokens are the only ones available.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll see if I can port the template engine used for file headers/copyright there.